# Can we store all the Teams meeting recordings inside a SharePoint site instead of the user OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-teams

Can we store all the Teams meeting recordings inside a SharePoint site instead of the user OneDrive?

currently when someone setup a Teams meeting and he record the meeting the meeting will get saved inside the user's onedrive. so can we change the location of the recording to be inside a

SharePoint site we create?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### The Native part

---

You need to specify Teams Channel which this Meeting is related to (**Option E**), when you start recording this meeting will be saved to "Files" of this Channel.

So the meetings scheduled in a Teams Channel, or started using "Meet Now" in a Teams Channel, the recording will be stored in the files section of that Channel under a folder called "Recordings." It will be available to all members of that particular Team

[image]

And as you know, the "Files" section of a Team Channel is in reality a SharePoint Library

---

### Go Further with Power Automate

---

If your business requirement to have ONE centralized SharePoint Site to host all your meetings recordings, you can create the following workflow :

- It will trigger when a new file has been created inside the
  user OneDrive (Check this : [Copy a Teams Meeting Recording](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Copy-a-Teams-Meeting-Recording-created-in-OneDrive-to-be-copied/td-p/844074)), in
  your scenario you can copy it to your SharePoint Site.

**But i would recommend the native one, I would recommend to have Multiple seperated SharePoint Site instead of one.**

Comment: thanks for been very helpful.

Comment: If you find it very helpful, thank you for marking my answer as a Accepted ☺☺